# I want people to perceive me as the robot I am

Tags: word-usage, grammar

> I want people to ***perceive*** me as the robot I am.

What does this sentence mean?

Is she wanted people treat him as a robot or human？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was said by [Sophia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophia_(robot)), an experimental robot.

It means that she wants people to understand that she's a robot, and not to think that she's a human.